# Connection between Unity 3d and MATLAB

Tags: c#, matlab, unity-game-engine, localization, connection

I'm working on a self-driving car project for unstructured environment on Unity 3d virtual environment, but I need to do the calculations for localization on MATLAB and I need to pass some variables from Unity to MATLAB. I have tried few codes from online people but all of them did not work at all. Can anyone please help me with this issue. I'm not familiar with C# at all.
I need to establish a proper connection between Unity 3d and MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Unity3d native plugin.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

From the native plugin dll, you should be able to follow this tutorial if your function is deployed.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/qs/create-a-c-net-application-that-calls-the-deployed-function.html

Or use ProcessStart from inside the native plugin if you want to just run a matlab locally as if you were running it from the commandline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads